# Swift Error: NSInternalInconsistencyException, 'Upload attempting to execute on non main queue! Only on the main queue.'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, twitter

I'm implementing a sign in with Twitter option on my app (with TwitterKit) but it keeps crashing on the function below - saveUserIntoFirebaseDatabase (when uploading the user data, image to Firebase database). I can't understand how OR why the function below needs to be in the main queue?

The user data is fetched and saved to the Firebase Auth section however it seems to crash after that when trying to save the user data to the Realtime Database & Storage?

```
fileprivate func saveUserIntoFirebaseDatabase() {

    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid,
    let name = self.name,
    let username = self.username,
    let email = self.email,
    let profileImage = profileImage,
    let profileImageUploadData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage, 0.3) else { Service.dismissHud(self.hud, text: "Error", detailText: "Failed to save user.", delay: 3); return }
    let filename = UUID().uuidString

    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("profile_images").child(filename)
    storageRef.putData(profileImageUploadData, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in

        if let err = err {
            Service.dismissHud(self.hud, text: "Error", detailText: "Failed to save user with error: \(err)", delay: 3);
            return
        }

        // Firebase 5 Update: Must now retrieve downloadURL
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (downloadURL, err) in
        guard let profileImageUrl = downloadURL?.absoluteString else { return }
        print("Successfully uploaded profile image into Firebase storage with URL:")

        let dictionaryValues = ["name": name,
                                "email": email,
                                "username": username,
                                "profileImageUrl": profileImageUrl]
        let values = [uid : dictionaryValues]

        Database.database().reference().child("users").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (err, ref) in
            if let err = err {
                Service.dismissHud(self.hud, text: "Error", detailText: "Failed to save user info with error: \(err)", delay: 3)
                return
            }
            print("Successfully saved user info into Firebase database")
            // after successfull save dismiss the welcome view controller
            self.hud.dismiss(animated: true)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        })
    })
}
```

The MainTabBarController I have setup has the following to see if the current user is logged in, if not they get re-directed to the Welcome Controller. Could this be the cause?

```
fileprivate func checkLoggedInUserStatus() {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser == nil {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let welcomeController = WelcomeController()
            let welcomeNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: welcomeController)
            self.present(welcomeNavigationController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Just make sure your code runs on the main queue.

Comment: OK. I thought it was?...Maybe I should listen to Xcode more. I added Dequeue.main to the function and it worked. Pretty new to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to dismiss the viewcontroller on a background thread.